# How to Perform Memory-efficient Backpropagation in PyTorch When Using a Custom Loss Function?

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation

**Introduction**:

I'm working on a large-scale deep learning project using PyTorch and facing memory issues during backpropagation. I've implemented a custom loss function, and I need to know if there's a more memory-efficient way to perform backpropagation without compromising the custom loss computation.

**Code**:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class CustomLoss(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x, y):
        return torch.sum(x * y)

# My neural network
class Net(nn.Module):
    # ...
```

I tried using PyTorch’s built-in methods for backpropagation but they consume a lot of memory. I was expecting that the custom loss function could be optimized for better memory utilization.

What actually happened?

Memory consumption spiked during backpropagation, causing my script to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

1. Making `batch_size` smaller.
2. Making checkpoints with `torch.utils.checkpoint.checkpoint` (trade-off between computing and memory, see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/checkpoint.html))
3. Wherever possible, using in-place operations.

Answer (score 0):

Memory consumption during backprop is caused by needing to store a grad parameter for each model parameter, plus parameters stored for the optimizer state. It's not related to your loss function.

You can reduce memory usage by using a smaller batch size and training with gradient accumulation.